# Vue layout with named slots

Tags: vue.js, slot

Is it possible?
I have something like this:

```html
<template>
  <my-layout>
      <template #header>
          Some header html goes here
      </template>
      Body html here
  </my-layout>
</template>

<script>
import MyLayout from './MyLayout.vue'
export default {
    layout: MyLayout,
    components: {
        //MyLayout
    }
}
</script>
```

And template like that

```html
<template>
<div>
<slot name="header"/>
</div>
<slot/>
</template>
```

The default slot works, but "header" slot doesn't display itself (unless using MyLayout as standard component).

Comment: It doesn't explain how to deal with "global" layout.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a problem with the closing tags on the template you have given and it should be like the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="header"> </slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

After that, layout property only excepts strings or functions that return strings, so parent should be like the following:

```
<template>
  <my-layout>
    <template #header>
      Some header html goes here
    </template>
    Body html here
  </my-layout>
</template>

<script>
import MyLayout from "./MyLayout.vue";
export default {
  layout: "MyLayout",
  components: {
    //MyLayout
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope this solves your problem and have a nice day :)

Comment: Thx, alas it didn't work.